# Change trigger text

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$("a.question").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".answer").slideToggle('fast', function () {
        $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Show Question" : "Hide Question");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tSww/1/

.. now this almost works except when you click on the trigger first time, it doesn't now update the label, it works only from the second time its clicked.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what it should do?

Comment: comment was enough, -ve wasn't required :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead.

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.next(".answer").slideToggle('fast', function () {
  $this.text(function(i, text) {
    return text == 'Show Question' ? 'Hide Question' : 'Show Question';
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).is(':visible')
```

to

```
!$(this).is(':visible')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or change `:visible` to `:hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/9tSww/2/